# Async function error: "Type 'Promise<MyType[]>[]' is not assignable to type 'MyType[]' "

Tags: typescript

This function was fine until converted to async, and then my type annotations have not been in sync since attempting to make corrections:

```
export default async function formatCallRecordsForPGPromise(
  rawCalldata: CallRecord[],
): Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]> {
  const dataSortedbyPhoneNumber: PhoneNumberKeyedCallData = lodash.groupBy(rawCalldata,
    (record: CallRecord) => record.destination);

  const phoneNumberAndGroupedData: [string, CallRecord[]][] = Object
    .entries(dataSortedbyPhoneNumber);

  const allData: Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>[] = phoneNumberAndGroupedData
    .map(async (numberAndCallData: [string, CallRecord[]]) => {
      const phoneNumber = numberAndCallData[0];

      const selectCampaignId = 'SELECT id FROM campaign WHERE phoneNumber = $1';

      let campaign_id: number;
      try {
        campaign_id = await pgp.configured.one(
          selectCampaignId, phoneNumber, (queryResult: { id: number }) => queryResult.id,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }

      const formattedDataSet: SaveableCallRecord[] = numberAndCallData[1]
        .map((record: CallRecord) => {
          const {
            date, callerid, destination, description, account, disposition, seconds, uniqueid,
          } = record;

          const formattedData: SaveableCallRecord = {
            unique_id: uniqueid,
            caller_id: callerid,
            <more 
          };

          return formattedData;
        });

      return formattedDataSet;
    });

  const allDataFlattened = allData.flat();

  return allDataFlattened;
}
```

Error:

```
/*
const allDataFlattened: Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>[]
Type 'Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>[]' is not assignable to type 'SaveableCallRecord[]'.

Type 'Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'SaveableCallRecord': unique_id, caller_id, date, description, and 4 more.ts(2322)
*/
```

I have tried several minor tweaks but can't get the annotations to pass without lint errors. The desired return type is an array of `SaveableCallRecord`. Can anyone see the issue?

**Update**

```
  const allDataFlattened = (await allData).flat();
```

I get this error:

```
/*
const allDataFlattened: Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>[]
Type 'Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>[]' is not assignable to type 'SaveableCallRecord[]'.
  Type 'Promise<SaveableCallRecord[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'SaveableCallRecord': unique_id, caller_id, date, description, and 4 more.ts(2322)
*/
```

**Update 2**

```
  await Promise.all(allData);

  const allDataFlattened = allData.flat();

  return allDataFlattened;
```

Error remains the same.

I am still unsure how to solve this, although I continue to try. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you likely forgot to add an "await" `const allDataFlattened = (await allData).flat()`

Actually allData is an array of promises… you might have to solve them using something like `await Promise.all(allData)` good luck

Answer (score 0):

A colleague informed me that TSC compiler can't infer promise resolution on `allData`.

**Old code**

```
await Promise.all(allData);

const allDataFlattened = allData.flat();

return allDataFlattened;
```

```
// replace old code with:
return Promise.all(allData).then((data) => data.flat())
```

Comment: Solution 2 is nonsensical.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you advise on how to correct it, if there is a way to?

Comment: You don't use the result of `await Promise.all(allData)`. `Promise.all` doesn't modify the array you pass to it and your type assertion just suppresses the type error. Solution 2 will never work

Comment: @AluanHaddad, okay then, I will remove it to avoid confusing others